# Metro-like theme for WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, themes, java-metro-framework, zune

I would like to know where i can get the theme that looks like Zune application for Windows (or MetroTwit) for WPF.

I google it but i only get the theme for Silverlight 4, not WPF.

Comment: Try taking a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408211/A-Zune-Style-Application-Template-for-WPF-and-Silv It's a Zune Style application template for WPF and Silverlight - all MVVM based and nice and easy to use - I've just published it so hopefully you or someone else will find it useful!

Comment: Very cool - can the metro styling be used without the MVVM plumbing? That bit looks cool, too, but I have an existing project that I'd like to re-style.

Comment: Yeah it'll work without the MVVM plumbing - just look at MainWindow and MainView xaml files, there should be enough there (and in the ZuneResourceDictionary) xamls for you to use :)

Comment: Great, I'll give it a whirl!

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592326/making-wpf-applications-look-metro-styled-even-in-windows-7-window-chrome-t

Answer (score 46):

Resurrecting a dead post, perhaps, self promoting? More than certain, however, I've (relatively recently) started a Metro theme pack largely based on stuff I've created in MahTweets and from the Silverlight Cosmopolitan theme pack specifically for *WPF*

https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro

Usage is simple, just

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

There are some caveats over the way WPF handles theming from other assemblies that you will have to look into.

It's free, open source and would love further contributions if others are looking for this sort of thing in WPF.

Comment: Looks great, thanks! Would love a metro-styled modal/non-modal window & dialog box - perhaps based on Tim Heuer's FloatableWindow project? http://floatablewindow.codeplex.com/

Comment: Will this work with silverlight 4-5 ?

Comment: This is awesome, and still works well. Thanks Jenkins! I'm having a problem right now that I am using mahApps to solve. The only thing that I'm asking now is what is the best way to position these tiles.