# How can I create this design on Windows 7?

Tags: .net, microsoft-metro

I had installed MS Office 2012 on Windows 7. Can I design my app in office 2013 style with Visual Studio 2012 and standard means(may be wpf?) like this

[image: img]

Comment: Yes; you can do that in WPF.  What have you tried? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thanks.I have trouble with all) i'm young developer in .net. I doesn'n now how change border aroun window, how change min max button(in right top angle), and i wasn't sured that i can design metro style app only with wpf(because i see people recommend use MahApps.Metro http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/ e.g in this theme http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458382/metro-like-theme-for-wpf )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indeed looks like a Window with the borderless window style set, a red/orange border, an image or two, some TextBlocks and some retemplated/restyled buttons - if done in WPF. You could also do something similar in Windows Forms, plain old GDI/GDI+ or Direct3D/Direct2D. Even HTML if that is your language of choice. For a Windows 7 app though WPF would be best and would be the best path to learn practices useful in Windows 8 development as well. If upgrade to Windows 8 is possible though (there are some pretty good deals for upgrade to Windows 8 from any other Windows) - I would consider going straight to Windows 8.

Comment: Thanks. If i could designing app for windows 7 in metro-style without using others frameworks(only wpf) it's very good )