# Why doesn't WPF show Windows 8 style buttons in Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

This is a Windows 8 style button:

[image]

And this is a button in .NET 4.5 WPF app:

[image]

Any ideas why WPF doesn't show the native Windows 8 style buttons? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Here is something similiar...not sure if it will help or not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458382/metro-like-theme-for-wpf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you can do is use a custom WPF styling from [HERE](http://www.rudiv.se/Blog/programming/windows-8-release-preview-button-textbox-style-wpf).

Below is a screenshot of the styles as applied to the same WPF application in multiple states. The top is obviously Aero themed, and the bottom set is with the newly applied styles.

[image]

And here is a link to the [XAML](https://web.archive.org/web/20130722034224/http://www.rudiv.se/win8_theme_xaml.htm).

Comment: These are some very nice styles.

Comment: @RudiVisser Thanks for creating them. `:)`

Comment: The styles don't work with other themes though. Colors are hard coded rather than use SystemColors

Comment: The XAML link is broken

Comment: @GuyGodin: The colours cannot be changed, so it's okay to keep them fixed. But they're still not accurate, I needed to change them all from real Windows 8.1 screenshots. And RadioButton and CheckBox also need some fixup, which is not included in this theme.

Answer (score 2):

WPF does not use any native Windows controls - it comes with its own controls and styles for different Windows versions. On Windows 7 you can find the following assemblies

```
PresentationFramework.Aero.dll
PresentationFramework.Classic.dll
PresentationFramework.Luna.dll
PresentationFramework.Royale.dll
```

and I guess there is a new one for Windows 8. Because WPF is not build upon native controls it is possible to have a XP-style WPF application on Windows 7 and a Windows-7-style application on Windows XP.

If you want to match the native Windows 8 UI better than what WPF offers out of the box, you will have to create your own styles - probably based on the styles provided by WPF.